# add component to head section

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, lightning-aura-components

How  to add a lightning component (.cmp) to the head section of the template that is applied to all pages.

Is there any way to add lightning components to the ‘Login’, ‘SelfRegistration’ and ‘ForgotPassword’ pages? As when i tried and it cannot be done

Comment: I don't think its possible yet, but its good idea and should be posted on IdeaExchange

Comment: If you are talking about a Visualforce Template, take a look at Lightning Out: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm